# How do I switch between two views being visible?

Tags: java, android

I am making an application that helps score a table tennis game. I am at the final stages but I am having trouble with switching the server around every two points. I have given it a lot of thought but I can only get it to switch once. I know it is probably an easy solution but it's just not coming to me.

Here's how I am switching it once. I am using a count each time the button is pressed and when it reaches a number divisible by 2 it switches to the right.. However, using this logic is making it difficult to switch back! Thanks in advance.

```
    public void serveSwitch() {
    TextView leftServe = findViewById(R.id.leftServe);
    TextView rightServe = findViewById(R.id.rightServe);
    serverCount++;
    if (server.serve=="left") {
        if (serverCount % 2 == 0) {
            rightServe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            leftServe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `if (server.serve.equals("left") ){`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Dom.F in java, you can't compare strings with == sign, but use `.equals()` method instead

Comment: This part of the statement is working, it decides which side is starting the service. The part I'm struggling with is the logic on how to switch visibilities every two points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The part I'm struggling with is the logic on how to switch visibility every two points

If I get your point right, you want to toggle the visibility from off to on every two points and vice versa

You can do something like:

```
...
if (server.serve=="left") {
    if (serverCount % 2 == 0) {

        switch (rightServe.getVisibility()) {
            case View.GONE:
                rightServe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case View.VISIBLE:
                rightServe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }

        switch (leftServe.getVisibility()) {
            case View.GONE:
                leftServe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case View.VISIBLE:
                leftServe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Note: I left the equality as-is as you say there is no problem with it. but in general you should use `.equals()` when it comes to compare strings in java.

Comment: This is it! Thanks for the help. I guess I need to read up on switch statements. (thanks for the advice on .equals() I will use that going forward)